# Unable to install anything on AWS ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I thought of migrating my php application from shared hosting to AWS. however i'm facing some difficult while installing packages, whenever i try to install a package it saying connecting to some xyz server and halts, the installation does not proceed. I followed below steps

```
1.) I created amazon AWS free tier account
2.) I created a security group policy
3.) I generated a elastic IP from the pool
4.) I created an AWS ec2 instance using Ubuntu x64 v16 (Did all the setup and was fine)
5.) Generated the .pem key and downloaded it, also connected via SSH using the key, i'm able to connect
6.) I then associated the Elastic IP to the instance and restarted the instance
```

whenever i try to connect to the public IP address it says server took too long to respond or is not accessible. I thought might be i need to install Apache

I'm trying to install Apache, also not only Apache even if i run sudo update && upgrade it just shows a message connecting to server and hangs up!

What my be the problem? Where did i go wrong?

Comment: You're connecting to the elastic IP, not the IP before you restarted the instance?

Comment: i connected on the same as well, but landed up with the same problem, this process i followed when terminating the previous instance and again creating a new one.

Comment: What should be the ideal process?

Comment: So after the elastic IP was attached it was connectable at all? And you checked the console screen and grabbed the "Public IP" from your instance?

Comment: This seems to be about system administration rather than programming, so it's off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mokugo-devops yes it was

Comment: And you confirm SSH does not work on the new IP?

Comment: I don't know it automatically started working now, i again created the instance. My mistake was that i was alloting the elastic ip and security policies which i hd already created. When i created new security policy at the time of setup and then allocated and associated new elastic up generated, everything worked fine like charm.